# How to get Yahoo Gemini Publisher API reports?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

When I log into Yahoo Gemini Publisher dashboard (located https://gemini.yahoo.com/publisher), I can see reports for the Publisher IDs I have configured.  I am now trying to get this same data from the Gemini REST APIs, but am running into some confusion and errors.

According to https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini-publishers/docs/gemini-publisher-reporting.html I need to get an OAuth2 access token (which I can do successfully through https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=GEMINI_CONSUMER_KEY&redirect_uri=MY_URL&response_type=token&language=en-us browser redirect) and make a call to https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/reports/publisher/ to get the reports.  However when I do, I get a cryptic response:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/reports/publisher/ \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer [omitted]' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{ ... cube JSON stuff ... }'

{"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"additional_authorization_required\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""}}
```

The OAuth token was granted with access to the Gemini API.  I have tried getting the OAuth token through both the Explicit and Implicit methods, with the same result.  Thinking that it may be a access issue, I increased the permission granted to the other APIs as well (Profile, Contacts, etc) with no change.

I noticed there are a separated set of Gemini APIs listed on https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/.  These APIs are located at https://api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/reports/custom/ and when I POST to them it accepts my OAuth token, however the "cubes" for these APIs require an "Advertiser ID" which I am not sure where to get or if I am am using the right API.

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "errIndex": -1,
        "code": "E40000_INVALID_INPUT",
        "message": "Entity (publisher or advertiser id) not available",
        "description": ""
    }
],
"response": { ... }
}
```

The message would seem to indicate I could pass in a Publisher ID, however when I include that in the "filter" it does not work.

When I try to call https://api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/advertiser/ I receive no advertisers back.

Which API should I be using?  If it is https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest/reports/publisher/ then am I omitting some required request data or am I getting the token wrong?  If I am supposed to use https://api.gemini.yahoo.com/v2/rest/reports/custom/ then how do I get the publisher data (or my "Advertiser ID")?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently Yahoo has deprecated the Gemini publishing APIs and moved this functionality to Flurry (whose APIs require different authentication).  https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/api/code/publishing/

Comment: Flurry is mobile only. Gemini is still maintained and currently on V3.